# How to update ThymeLeaf using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, maven, thymeleaf

I have changed the version inside spring-boot-dependencies-1.2.7.RELEASE.pom file, but I am getting [this](https://gist.github.com/cescoferraro/6015f0d142bcd4570c71) error.I have update both these both tags

```
<thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.ALPHA03</thymeleaf.version>
<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>1.3.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its been a while you have posted that but hoping this will be helpful to others.As of now Springboot can not auto configure Thymeleaf 3.0. You will need exclude ThymeleafAutoConfiguration class and provide your custom configuration. There are well documented steps you may refer to at following url:

https://gist.github.com/seanhinkley/6eab2130ceea857c160b

Layout Dialect is not managed by Thymeleaf Team it is still a open issue.

https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/issues/68

Other option is to wait till Springboot officially supports Thymeleaf 3.0.

**Update :**

Springboot has added support for Auto configuration of Thymeleaf 3.0 , in 1.4.x versions. By Default, Springboot still uses Thymeleaf 2.1, but it is possible to configure it to use 3.0.

```
<properties>
     <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
     <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

Reference to official documentation :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3

Reference to Sample :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-thymeleaf3